# Apache2/Tomcat8 virtual host JSF application returning incorrect urls (the app name is duplicated)

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, tomcat8

I have a website (http://www.goodfoodwaiheke.org) configured as a virtual host on Apache2. The virtual hosting configuration redirects traffic from apache2 to tomcat8 via these conf parameters:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.goodfoodwaiheke.org
    ServerAlias goodfoodwaiheke.org

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/coop/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/coop/
</VirtualHost>
```

On tomcat, the /coop/ part of the address invokes the JSF application in coop.war. This seems to work. The correct welcome page is served except for one problem. The url for static resources are being served incorrectly. For example, the url of the background image on the welcome page, which is actually in http://www.goodfoodwaiheke.org/coop/resources/images/GoodFoodWaiheke4.png is served to the browser as http://www.goodfoodwaiheke.org/coop/coop/resources/images/GoodFoodWaiheke4.png   (i.e. the coop app name is duplicated in the url). This is causing static resources to not work. Although I can sort of understand why this may be happening I am unsure of how to fix it. I know I could offload the static resources onto the Apache2 server but for various reasons I would like the war file to be self-contained and for tomcat to be responsible for serving the whole site.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to what I need to change.

Comment: So it works if you don't use jsf in this webapp?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It is a jsf app. It has previously worked ok when deployed on Amazon Web Services. I think the virtual host redirection to tomcat might be the problem. I'm just not sure how I could modify the app or deploy it differently to avoid this problem.

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. This is even not a programming problem. This is a serverconfig problem.